# How to get minutes and seconds(mm:ss) from a timedelta object in python

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

I'm writing a **code** in which I have added Time duration for each utterance(given as list of durations for each utterance) and the result is a **timedelta** showing sum of duration of all utterances. I need the result in only minutes and seconds**(mm:ss)** format.

## Code

```
def add_time(timeList):
   sums = datetime.timedelta()
   for i in timeList:
      x = datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%M:%S.%f')
      d=datetime.timedelta(minutes=x.minute,seconds=x.second,microseconds=x.microsecond)
    sums += d
    print(str(sums))
    return sums
add_time(['00:04.0', '00:15.2', '1:10.4'])
```

## Output

The output is like this:

```
 0:01:29.600000
 Out[148]: datetime.timedelta(0, 89, 600000)
```

How can I get minutes and seconds from a timedelta object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like this should work:

```
 "{}:{:02d}".format(*divmod(sums.seconds, 60))
```